# Excel VBA populates one set of cells from Textstream but ignores the next 22 sets. Tried everything I can think of

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to populate some cells from a TSV file. I can find no reason why this doesn't work. "Break on all errors" is set - it throws no errors. The array is perfectly populated from the textstream. The guard clauses work as intended. The column offset variable incrementing and resulting address are correct. The cells are not locked and sheet protection is not enabled anyway. And it works fine for the very first set of numbers/text/date. But for the remaining 22 sets it does nothing. I've tried the `.Range("A1")` and `.MergedArea` devices after the `.Offset(...)`. Office365 Pro. I'm stumped.

```
Sub chartTextData(ByVal pathToData As String, dateEarliest As Date, Optional ByVal strFile As String)
    
    On Error GoTo LoopExit
                            Debug.Print Now() & " chartTextData BEGIN"
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim TxtStream As textStream
    Dim linebuffer
    Dim myArray
    Dim cellAnchor As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Debug.Assert i = 0

    Set cellAnchor = ActiveSheet.Range("D39")   '38 on some
    
         Set TxtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(pathToData & strFile, ForReading, False, TristateUseDefault)
Do While Not TxtStream.AtEndOfStream

    linebuffer = TxtStream.ReadLine
    '  0     1     2        3            4        5   6 7
    '33.19,$F$38,good,No Need to Act,11/20/2014,2100,DB,2
    myArray = Split(linebuffer, vbTab, , vbTextCompare)
    'header row, skip it
    If myArray(1) Like "*DATE*" Then GoTo JumpHereToBypassOlderThanDateEarliest
    If myArray(1) < dateEarliest Then GoTo JumpHereToBypassOlderThanDateEarliest

    'Set cellAnchor = ActiveSheet.Range(myArray(1))  'eg, "$D$39"
    cellAnchor.Offset(0, i).Value2 = CDbl(myArray(0))  'test value
    cellAnchor.Offset(3, i).Value2 = CDate(myArray(1))  'Date
    cellAnchor.Offset(2, i).Value2 = myArray(2)  'time
    cellAnchor.Offset(4, i).Value2 = myArray(3)  'Tech
                                'Debug.Print myArray(0)
    i = i + 2                   'merged cells, 2 per
                                'Debug.Print i & " <--i"
    If i >= 46 Then GoTo LoopExit
                                    
JumpHereToBypassOlderThanDateEarliest:
Loop
    
LoopExit:
    TxtStream.Close
    Set TxtStream = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.Calculate
            Debug.Print Now() & " chartTextData END"
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you put a break inside the loop?

Comment: Are you sure this works as expected `If myArray(1) < dateEarliest` ?  Later when populating the cell you use `CDate(myArray(1))` which suggests it's not already recognized as a date value?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I've put breakpoints inside the loop and looked at the Locals. Nothing is amiss. Held my finger down on F8 - behaves the same.

Comment: @TimWilliams I see your point. But it's not an issue. I can omit the cdate and it still populates the first full run through the loop. And the TSV file is date-time sequential - the FSO won't happen upon any dates earlier than dates it's already seen. I'm passing #5/10/2022# to it and it's skipping thousands of rows perfectly - loop body starts with a May 10, 2022 row. Edit: added last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This **works**, and I don't know why. Not using **i** for column-offset, Activating top cell of each vertical range to be populated, and re-Setting cellAnchor to it.

````
Sub chartTextData(ByVal pathToData As String, dateEarliest As Date, Optional ByVal strFile As String)
    
    On Error GoTo LoopExit
                            Debug.Print Now() & " chartTextData BEGIN"
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim TxtStream As textStream
    Dim linebuffer
    Dim myArray
    Dim cellAnchor As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set cellAnchor = ActiveSheet.Range("D39")   '38 on some
        cellAnchor.Activate
        
         Set TxtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(pathToData & strFile, ForReading, False, TristateUseDefault)
Do While Not TxtStream.AtEndOfStream

    linebuffer = TxtStream.ReadLine
    '  0     1     2        3            4        5   6 7
    '33.19,$F$38,good,No Need to Act,11/20/2014,2100,DB,2
    myArray = Split(linebuffer, vbTab, , vbTextCompare)
    'header row, skip it
    If myArray(1) Like "*DATE*" Then GoTo JumpHereToBypassOlderThanDateEarliest
    If myArray(1) < dateEarliest Then GoTo JumpHereToBypassOlderThanDateEarliest

    cellAnchor.Offset(0, 0).Value2 = CDbl(myArray(0))  'test value
    cellAnchor.Offset(3, 0).Value2 = CDate(myArray(1))  'Date
    cellAnchor.Offset(2, 0).Value2 = myArray(2)  'time
    cellAnchor.Offset(4, 0).Value2 = myArray(3)  'Tech
                                'Debug.Print myArray(0)
    i = i + 2                   'merged cells, 2 per
    
        cellAnchor.Offset(0, 2).Activate
    Set cellAnchor = ActiveCell
    
    If i >= 46 Then GoTo LoopExit
                                    
JumpHereToBypassOlderThanDateEarliest:
Loop
    
LoopExit:
    TxtStream.Close
    Set TxtStream = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.Calculate
            Debug.Print Now() & " chartTextData END"
End Sub
```**
````

Comment: You can skip the `Activate` here: `Set cellAnchor = cellAnchor.Offset(0, 2)`